# Acessando dados armazenados no cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

No login, armazeno informações do usuário logado em um cookie (nome, senha, etc...)

Como faço para acessar esse cookie e resgatar informações dele?

Por exemplo, quero que na barra superior fique aparecendo o nome do usuario logado, pela minha lógica teria que buscar o nome que ja está armazenado no arquivo e joga-lo em uma `@Viewbag` determinada no `controller`, está correta essa forma de pensar? E qual a maneira mais estética e correta de se fazer essa ação?

Segue o exemplo de quando faz a autenticação:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Login form, string retornarurl)
    {
        var usr = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.nome == form.nome);

        if (usr == null || !usr.CheckPassword(form.passwordHash))
            ModelState.AddModelError("nome", "Usuário ou senha estão incorretos ou não existe");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(form);

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usr.nome, true);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin" );

    }
```

Comment: Você está usando algum provedor de autenticação como o Membership ou ainda o Identity?

Comment: Creio que não. Eu mesmo criei um repositório para fazer a autenticação, que posteriormente será feito através de um formulário personalizado.

Comment: Pode colocar uma parte do código dele na sua pergunta?

Comment: Na vdd ele esta no controller mesmo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você usa a maneira antiga, que era usada no Web Forms. Pode ser feito desta forma:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

string cookiePath = ticket.CookiePath;
DateTime expiration = ticket.Expiration;
bool expired = ticket.Expired;
bool isPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent;
DateTime issueDate = ticket.IssueDate;
string name = ticket.Name;
string userData = ticket.UserData;
string version = ticket.Version;
```

Recomendo você dar uma olhada no [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity), que realiza um gerenciamento mais interessante do usuário e os ciclos de registro, login e registro de logins externos.

Comment: Hm... interessante. Mas nesse modo ai, eu teria que criar um repositório ?

Comment: Por que você precisa criar um repositório? [Reimplemente `Principal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal(v=vs.110).aspx). Fica muito mais elegante.

Comment: E você teria algum exemplo pratico de como seria a autenticação nesse modo?

Comment: Nunca precisei reimplementar porque uso o ASP.NET Identity atualmente (antes usava o ASP.NET Membership), mas de repente posso fazer isso como um exercício. [Recomendo este artigo para você](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV).

Comment: Entendi, eu andei dando uma estudada no Identity, porem por ele ser CodeFirst e criar tabelas diferentes, fica mais complicado pra mim por já ser um projeto existente e ter um banco de dados já criado. Vou dar uma olha no artigo recomendado.